# Don't click the Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i use a method to display an Alert Dialog, and the code is:

```
public void TidakTuntas()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertgagal  = new AlertDialog.Builder(MenuSoal.this);
    alertgagal.setMessage("Maaf, skor Anda hanya "+ skor +", dan target skor agar tuntas di tahap ini adalah "+ketuntasan+".. Silahkan coba kembali!");
    alertgagal.setTitle("SKOR LEVEL INI");
    alertgagal.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MenuSoal.this, MenuPrasoal.class);           
            intent.putExtra("kirim",terimas);
            startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertgagal.show();
}
```

If i don't click the OK button, and i click the other/outer side of the AlertDialog, it automatically dismissed,closed, and the method onClick for the setPositiveButton is not executed..
Can i set the AlertDialog, if the user don't click the OK button, the AlertDialog will not be dismissed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
alertgagal.setCancelable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you would use

```
alertgagal.setCancelable(false);
```

then it can only be dismissed by an action

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel the action that is triggered by the touch on the outside of your alert, try `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: You can not call that method unless you have an instance of alertdialog. As you can see he is not getting any instance of alertdialog by AlertDialog.Builder. Check out the doc for more detail. setCancelable is the way to go in this case.

Comment: thankyou for the comments :D i have seen this solution, but it doesn't work if we used the AlertDialog.Builder :D

Comment: @saiful103a : a trivial `dialog = alertgagal.create()` returns the dialog. (which you can show by `dialog.show()` afterward ...)

Comment: yes i know :) , since he is not getting any instance of AlertDialog that's why i pointed it out.If there was no way to solve his current problem we would've suggested to use alertgagal.create() this way. Since there is a way why complicate :) .